# Multiple forms onclick event only working for first form

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this has been asked befor but I can't seem to find it in a search
I have multiple forms on a page generated by php all with onCick event 
The problem is it only picks up the first event after that any other clicks produce same result from first click
Here is javascript

```
   function CompareScores(form)
    {

var scoreA = document.getElementById("score_A").value;
var scoreB = document.getElementById("score_B").value;

if(scoreA > scoreB){
     alert('Score A is Larger ' + scoreA)
    }else{
     alert('Score B is Larger ' + scoreB)
         }
    }
```

And the php generating forms

```
<?php
    while($i<=$numPrelimTeams) {

      if($i!=$e) {
?>
<form action="processScores.php" method="post"><p><u><?php echo $prelimTeam[$i]; ?>  -->  SCORE : <input type="text" class="small" id="score_A" name="score_A" size="1"></u></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="team_A" value="<?php echo $prelimTeam[$i]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="game" value="<?php echo $game_num; ?>">
     <p class="right">Game # <?php echo $game_num; ?> ) <input type="button" value="Enter Scores" onClick="CompareScores(this.form)"></p>
<?php
        }else{
?>
  <p><u><?php echo $prelimTeam[$i]; ?>  -->  SCORE : <input type="text" class="small" id="score_B" name="score_B" size="1"></u></p>
   <input type="hidden" name="team_B" value="<?php echo $prelimTeam[$i]; ?>">

    </form><br><br><br>


<?php
        $game_num++;
        $e=$e+2;
        } 
     $i++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the inputs or seeing the result, it's hard to tell for sure, but it looks like you might be generating multiple instances of this form on the same page, giving you multiple page elements named "score_A" and "score_B". document.getElementById will then become a bit ambiguous.

Since you're already sending the form object, use that instead:

```
var scoreA = form.score_A.value;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially a single problem with your code. You have multiple instances of the same ID.

To fix it, try something like this.

```
<input type="text" class="small score_A" name="score_A" size="1" />
```

Similarly

```
<input type="text" class="small score_B" name="score_B" size="1" />
```

Now, you can write a `querySelector` in your JS

```
function CompareScores(form) {
    var a = form.querySelector('.score_A').value;
    var b = form.querySelector('.score_B').value;
    //do something
}
```